# How to refresh/reload UICollectionView Header to update label showing item count in section

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to update UICollectionView headers when entering or deleting an item from a section.

Reloading sections works exactly how I would want it to work, but it affects the animation of removing a cell, which looks terrible.

I also tried invalidating the layout, but that didn't work.

I would like to be able to reload headers after deleting a cell, which I am doing like this:

```
   func deleteItem(sender: UIButton) {

    let point : CGPoint = sender.convert(.zero, to: collectionView)
    let i = collectionView!.indexPathForItem(at: point)
    let index = i

    addOneToCompletedCount()

    if index?.section == 0 {

        GlobalList.priorityArray.remove(at: (index?.item)!)
        self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [index!])
        print("deleted priority item")
        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1155)

    } else if index?.section == 1 {

        GlobalList.listItemArray.remove(at: (index?.item)!)
        self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [index!])
        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        print("deleted item")
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1155)

    } else {

        print("Could not delete item")

    }

    saveData()
    checkIfListEmpty()

}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try that? `let headerView = collectionView.supplementaryView(forElementKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: indexPath)`

Comment: Yep, in viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind

Comment: If you want to update header without reloadData, you can try that as soon as you removing cell.

Comment: Which index path do I use that at?

Comment: Could you share some code what you already did?

Comment: Sure can, just added it

Comment: Where do you update the header of the collectionView?

Comment: I used to delete the section and then add in back, but I tried updated the header with collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout(), which doesn't work